# Why I cannot set tableview's content inset?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a venueListViewController in a view, it is loaded but hidden (frame.origin.y is bigger than device's size)

When I show this controller's view, I want to set content offset and inset as shown below:

```
-(void)showVenueList{
    CGRect frame = self.venueListViewController.tableView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.venueListViewController.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.venueListViewController.tableView.contentOffset.x, -10)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    self.venueListViewController.tableView.frame = frame;
    [self.venueListViewController.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100,0,0,0)];
    [self.venueListViewController.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But nothing happens. How can I do that? Where should I do this?

Comment: Where are you calling this method showVenueList

Comment: In another view controller that includes venueListViewController as a property.

Comment: is venueListViewController tableviews datasource?

Comment: Yes. It is the datasource of the tableview